# ListView selected item not visible

Tags: android, android-listview

I have created a ListView on a dialog and I am showing the selected item by using

```
lv.setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_SINGLE);
lv.setItemChecked(num, true);
```

lv is my ListView.

num is the item index to be selected.

However, when the dialog is displayed, the selected item is not visible if it is in the bottom of the list. How do i show the selected item at the top?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use setSelection function.

like:

```
lv.setSelection(num);
```